# NoReverseMatch at /portal/

Tags: python, html, django, drop-down-menu

I have inherited a python/django web application that I am trying to get working on a new machine. On machine 1 (the original) every drop menu link works correctly and causes no errors. On machine 2, the new machine where the web application was copied to, one dropdown menu link causes the following error:

```
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value: Reverse for 'account_index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

The error refers to an html template file called "base-site.html". The client dropdown has identical code to the account dropdown. On machine 1 both work, on machine 2 the account one causes the error. The python app excerpts below show the code relevent to the dropdowns ...

For the account dropdown

```
From base-site.html:  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="{% url 'account_index' %}">Browse</a></li>
From account urls.py:  url(r'^/?$', 'account.views.account_index', name='account_index'),
```

For the client dropdown

```
From base-site.html:  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="{% url 'client_index' %}">Browse</a></li>
From client urls.py:  url(r'^$', 'client.views.client_index', name='client_index'),
```

Can someone suggest why the account dropdown would work on machine 1 and not on machine 2? How to solve this issue so it works on both machines? Could it be .pyc files carried over in the copy from 1 to 2?

Comment: Is the version of django the exact same and all other third party modules on both machines?

Comment: As far as the .pyc, why not do a normal deploy with some kind of source control (svn, hg, git, etc) rather than copy the entire contents? That seems very error prone and inefficient to me.

Comment: Python/Django/Apache etc the same on both machines. What we are aiming for is an app where once apache/python/django etc is installed, then we can drop the app folder and have it work with minimal effort.

Comment: you should look into fabric then, the copy and past thing is a really bad practice. I can install, format drives, install dependencies and have a new app server up and running in about five minutes and a single command line

Comment: More on point: How do you know re: django? Is the old machine running in a python virtual environment and the new one is not or vice versa? check the .wsgi file to very this, that will tell you what python executable the site is looking at and therefore if it's using the system python or a python virtual environment.

Comment: I am somewhat new to Django/Python but not new to Apache or web apps. I am not familiar with Fabric do you have a link for it? Since my last comment I have discovered that on the working machine I had Apache 2.2.22 with a matching mod_wsgi.so module and on the non-working one I had Apache 2.2.25 with a matching mod_wsgi.so module. Replacing the 2.2.25 with 2.2.22 corrected the error I was having but doesn't explain it.

Comment: this is fabric: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/. I can't explain your issue, except possibly that your at the bottom of your (old) config file you might have been pointing to a different install wsgi file

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I will look up Fabric for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

The machine showing the error is using django 1.4 when it needs to be using django 1.5. The url template scheme changed between versions and it is not backwards compatible (unfortunately).

```
pip install django==1.5
```

Also, delete your pyc files before restarting your dev server

```
find . -name "*pyc" | xargs rm
```

Comment: Ah, no. Checked Django versions on both machines and both report 1.5.1 final. Also as I said the exact same code/python/tools/modules works on machine 1 but this one piece fails on machine 2.